# Python unsupported operand int and tuple - trying to create list from Excel range

Tags: python, excel, tuples, openpyxl

This is a Python question using openpyxl:
I am trying to load a range of decimal data from 'B2:B8' into a list that I can then do mathematical operations on.
My problem: I don't understand why the code I used to load the list is creating an error when I try to e.g. sum it. I guess I did not load it properly, but I don't know where I went wrong. Thank you for any and all help (beginner here, sorry for the stupid questions).

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
#Open the excel file
wb = load_workbook('TestCase.xlsm',  read_only=True)
sht = wb['Data']
#create first list that will hold weights
weightListd17 = []
#cycle through the Excel range
for wd17 in sht.iter_rows(min_row=2,
                         max_row=8,
                         min_col=2,
                         max_col=2,
                         values_only=True):
     #load the range into my list
     weightListd17.append(wd17)
print(weightListd17)
'''This looks like:
[(0.3746726857190015,), (0.07621196092466757,), (0.05527166764688042,), 
(0.06828742220950017,), (0.1440061416059534,), (0.01962368942291444,), 
(0.2619264324710826,)]
'''
#Test:
print(sum(weightListd17))
#ERROR:
'''
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Emma Code\ExtractList.py", line 28, in <module>
print(sum(weightListd17))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

'''

Comment: You dont have a list of ints, you have a list of tuples. You cant sum tuples

Comment: @Chris Doyle - how would you suggest I create a normal list of numbers from the excel range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the value give you tuple type when you iterate `sht.iter_rows`. You will append tuple with `wd17`. One way to avoid is to modify the line:

```
# since wd17 is tuple, so access the `int` with [0] 
weightListd17.append(wd17[0])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked, as I can now sum. I am wondering if I could have created a list type instead of a tuple from the get-go, but that is probably a battle for another day! Happy holidays.